# Like button in react not save likes of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I made like button in react and it save my choises but it doesn't save the choices of my users and I don't think it even let only for users to mark like. What I do wrong?

This is the code of the button:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem("toggleButtonState");
    if (storedState) {
      setIsToggled(JSON.parse(storedState));
    }
  }, []);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = true;

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const newToggleState = !isToggled;
      setIsToggled(newToggleState);

      localStorage.setItem("toggleButtonState", JSON.stringify(newToggleState));
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Unauthorized access. Only logged-in users can click the button."
      );
    }
  };

  const buttonStyle = {
    padding: "8px 16px",
    borderRadius: "4px",
    backgroundColor: isToggled ? "#4CAF50" : "#f44336",
    color: "#fff",
    border: "none",
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontSize: "16px",
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleToggle} style={buttonStyle}>
      {isToggled ? "Unlike" : "Like"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ToggleButton;
```

And this is the component of the button:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Toggle Button Example</h1>
      <ToggleButton />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the end point in the server:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/api/authenticate", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (username === "user" && password === "password") {
    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, "secret_key", { expiresIn: "1h" });

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, token });
  } else {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, message: "Invalid credentials" });
  }
});

app.listen(8181, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 8181");
});
```

And this is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 256,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 256,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 1024,
  },
  biz: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
    minlength: 0,
    maxlength: 9,
  },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And if it's relevant so this is the userRouter:

```
const validateRegistration = require("./usersValidations/registraion");
const validateSignin = require("./usersValidations/SignUp");
const {
  comparePassword,
  generateHashPassword,
} = require("../../services/bcrypt");
const { generateAuthToken } = require("../../services/token");
const _ = require("lodash");
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("./userModel");
const auth = require("../../middlewares/authorization");
const chalk = require("chalk");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateRegistration(req.body);
  if (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright(error.details[0].message));
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Registration Error: User already registered"));
    return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");
  }

  user = new User(
    _.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password", "biz", "likes" > []])
  );

  user.password = generateHashPassword(user.password);
  await user.save();
  res.send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateSignin(req.body);
  if (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright(error.details[0].message));
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Invalid email"));
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");
  }

  const validPassword = comparePassword(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!validPassword) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Invalid password"));
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");
  }

  res.json({
    token: generateAuthToken(user),
  });
});

router.get("/userinfo", auth, (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;

  User.findById(user._id)
    .select(["-password", "-createdAt", "-__v"])
    .then((user) => res.send(user))
    .catch((errorsFromMongoose) => res.status(500).send(errorsFromMongoose));
});

module.exports = router;
```

If something missin pls let me know and don't vote against my Q. cuz I don't wanna to be block.
Thank u very much!

Comment: Did you get any error mesages from your users? Or the button just dont't do nothing? I see you are using the local storage... Do you think all of your's users has a browser compatible with that? Besides, this app is served static?

Comment: @PipoBizelli No I didn't get any errors massages. And the button is working but the problem is the button doens't save the choices of the users. if I will click unlike in some user and after that I will connect with another user this user will see the last user click like although that he didn't click on like. In the bottom line the data of the button doesn't save for any user. And the users I talking about them they users I create to check this.

Comment: @Omer it seem like you have more than 1 bug; when you "*connect with another user*" you should update the state back to initial values, like cause the component to re-render and I *guess* when you refresh that last user's "*like*" would be removed? But then for the rest we'd have to work on your project together to fix bugs. Or maybe just split your issues into multiple questions, keep 1 post focused on 1 specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your this comment [Like button in react not save likes of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096538/like-button-in-react-not-save-likes-of-users/76124301#comment134206733_76096538)

As far as I understand your issue, if you click on the like button, it is working for you, but if you are logging in with another user / acting as another user, you are still seeing the previous like button.

For that,

1. You should create a logout feature. When you log out, you need to
   remove all of the local storage but keep information in the database
   on the server side. When a new user login, you will fetch only his
   like status, then show it to him from the server side.
2. Anyhow, If that doesn't fit your requirements If you don't want to logout, then change the json format while saving it to the local storage and database.

   `localStorage.setItem("toggleButtonState", JSON.stringify([ { userId: 1, postId: 1, liked: true } ]));`

   after that, filter that array for the current user from the local storage or database, and get the like status.